# C# Adding until no <value> left -For-loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, ip-address

5On a network calculator, I have the IP entered by user and the subnet as well as the Network address for said host IP entered. (Have calculated)

All I need now is to make a for-loop which counts upwards until the last ip address is reached (broadcast).

So;

```
int IP1 = 192,IP2 = 168,IP3 = 0,IP4 = 0, subnet = 255.255.0.0;// 192.168.0.0/16
int totalIPs = 65536; //hostbits^2

do
        {
            for (int a = IP1; a < 255; a++)
            {
                IP1++;
                for (int b = IP2; b < 255; b++)
                {
                    IP2++;
                    for (int c = IP3; c < 255; c++)
                    {
                        IP3++;
                        for (int d = IP4; d < 255; d++)
                        {
                            totalIPs= totalIPs - 1;
                            IP4++;
                        }
                        IP4 = 0;
                    }
                    IP3 = 0;
                }
                IP2 = 0;
            }
        }
        while (totalIPs > 0);
```

I know that there is something terribly wrong with this for-loop, but I just can't seem to get it.

What I need is the broadcast address, counting up from the original IP value (in this case 192.168.0.0) and count from there to the last IP (now that we know how many IPs it has to count)

So when octet 4(d) gets to 255, then octet 3(c) goes 1 up, then reset octet 4(d) and so on, Like a clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to go through all that, you're just adding numbers here.

First you do this:

```
int carry = 0;
IP4 += totalIPs;

carry = IP4 / 254;
IP4 = IP4 % 254;

if(carry>0) // Need to spill over IP3
{
   IP3 += carry;

   carry = IP3 / 254;
   IP3 = IP3 % 254;

   if(carry > 0)  // Spill over to IP2
   {
       IP2 += carry;

       carry = IP2 / 254;
       IP2 = IP2 % 254;

       IP1 += carry;
       IP1 %= 254;    // No spill-over here
   }
}
```

It's a bit cumbersome because you chose to use 4 ints for the IP parts, but it'll get the job done with no loops.

Comment: if it were actually a /16, you just wouldn't want 0.0 and 255.255 - but 192.168 is conventionally a set of 256 /24's. [so you want 192.168.{0-255}.{1-254}]

Comment: hmm, it should be a way to do it no matter what input i insert?
@zmbq sorry i meant it was meant to be up to 255!

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
int IP1 = 192, IP2 = 168, IP3 = 0, IP4 = 0;

for (int i1 = IP1; i1 < 256; i1++) {
    for (int i2 = IP2; i2 < 256; i2++) {
        for (int i3 = IP3; i3 < 256; i3++) {
            for (int i4 = IP4; i4 < 256; i4++) {
                string ip = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", i1 i2, i3, i4);
                ...
            }
            IP4 = 0;
        }
        IP3 = 0;
    }
    IP2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: This just leaves the program "hanging"?

Comment: What have you placed exactly inside the most inner loop? The loops do not hang, however they will iterate about one million times! Did you intend to loop only the two last octets? That would make 65536 iterations.

Comment: Hmm, well, i have `totalIPs-1;` :P Do i need anything else to calculate the last IP ?

Comment: I figured it out, i stopped it from doing an endless loop, though what i get back is `192.0.0.0`as the last IP address, which it isn't.

Comment: Do not use `IP1` - `IP4` but `i1` - `i4`! `IP1` - `IP4` are just the starting addresses! In my example with `String.Format` I use  `i1` - `i4`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can lean on the .NET Framework:

```
byte IP1 = 192, IP2 = 168, IP3 = 0, IP4 = 0;
int totalIPs = 65536;

int littleEndian = IP4 + (IP3 << 8) + (IP2 << 16) + (IP1 << 24) + totalIPs;
var bigEndian = BitConverter.GetBytes(littleEndian).Reverse().ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(new System.Net.IPAddress(bigEndian));
```